# How to find the function by given conditions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $ f(2-x)=f(2+x)$ and $ f(4-x)=f(4+x)$ for all $x$ and $f(x)$ is a function for which $$\int_{0}^2 f(x) dx=5.$$ Is it possible to obtain the function from given conditions?

Edit: OP was actually interestred in the answer to the following question:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are such functions, there are probably even infinite many of them.

Take a function $g$ which is symmetric with respect to the axis $x=2$ and $x=4$, i.e. $g(2-x)= g(2+x)$ and $g(4-x)=g(4+x)$. Assume that $\int_0^2 g(x) \, dx=a\ne 0$. Then $f=\frac 5 a f$ satisfies your conditions.

Valid choices for $g$ (NOT $f$) are $g=1$, or $g(x)=\sin^2(\frac \pi 2 x)$.

---

As OP was actually interested in a different question, I will address this one as well.

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$,
>   $f(2+x)=f(2-x)$ and $f(4+x)=f(4-x)$.
>
> Then for $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in [0, 2]$ we have  $$(1):~~~~f(4n+x)=f(x) ~~~~~  
>  \text{ and } (2):~~~~ f(4n+2+x)=f(2-x) ~~~~~ $$

This shows that $f$ is completely determined by its values in $[0,2]$.

Proof: We prove this by induction. If $n=0$ then there is nothing to prove
Now let (1) and (2) hold for all $n\le k$.
Then
$$(1): ~~~f(4(k+1)+x)=f(4k+(4+x))\stackrel 1 {=}f(4+x)=f(4-x)=f(2+(2-x))=f(2-(2-x))=f(x)$$
where in 1 I used the induction hypothesis.
Similarly
$$(2):~~~f(4(k+1)+2+x)=f(4k+6+x)=f(6+x)=f(4+(2+x))=f(4-(2+x))=f(2+x)=f(2-x)$$

---

> Let $f$ be as above. Then for $n \in \mathbb Z$, $\int_{2n}^{2n+2} f(x)
>  \, dx = \int_0^2 f(x) \, dx$.

Proof: We have to consider two cases:
First, let $n$ even, i.e n=2k for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. Then 
$$\int_{2n}^{2n+2} f(x) \, dx= \int_{4k}^{4k+2} f(x) \, dx= \int_0^2 f(4k+x) \, dx =\int_0^2 f(x) \, dx $$
Now let $n$ even, i.e. $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. Then 
$$\int_{2n}^{2n+2} f(x) \, dx = \int_{4k+2}^{4k+4} f(x) \, dx= \int_0^2 f(4k+2+x) \, dx = \int_0^2 f(2-x) \, dx= \int_{-2}^0 f(-x) \, dx =\int_0^2 f(x) \, dx.$$

Using these results you should be able to find the answer to your problem.

Comment: but in my text the main question is to evaluate the $\int_{0}^{50} f(x)dx$ on the basis of given conditions?

Comment: if you take $f(x)=1$ the it does not satisfy the given value of integral from o to 2

Comment: My $g$ is your $f$

Comment: The value of the integral $\int_0^{50} f(x) \, dx$ is independent of the choice of $f$ satisfying your conditions.

Comment: please explain in more detail. I want to integrate the f(x) from 0 to 50. How can i do it?

Comment: I exchanged the roles of $f$ and $g$ in my answer. You have to split up the integral in smaller integral and then use the symmetry properties of your function. A subset of the functions satisfying your  conditions are periodic functions (like the ones in my examples). If $g$ is periodic with period $2$, then $\int_0^{50} g(x) \, dx= 25*\int_0^2 g(x) \, dx$.

Comment: According to your concept what will be your final answer

Comment: Isn't the final answer obvious from here? The "hard" part is to show that its independent of the function.

Comment: I failed to solve it thats why i am asking and in my text its answers are option a, b and d

Comment: Are you only interested in the solution, or dou you want to understand why it is the right one/ why all a,b, d are right?

Comment: I want to understand very deeply. Not only intersted in answer

Comment: Then you have to think for yourself. I will edit my answer such that it answers your real question. While I do that, you should try to integrate $f$ from $2$ to $4$, then from $4$ to $6$, and so on.

Comment: ok i m trying and thnks for explaing the concept

Comment: i got your periodic concept but how are you sure that the period of $f$ is 2. It may be possible its period will in between of 0 to 2

Comment: i am fully  satisfied by your answer and not thought like you as you did well in question to prove it. I was trying to find the period of function by replacement technique, but failed to got any substitution. How can i find the period by by appropriate substitution or replacement.

Comment: (1) of my answer shows that $f$ is periodic with a period of 4. (2) Is the first half of showing that each period is symmetric. When calculating the integrals, I also used substitution (e.g in the first integral $y(x)=4k+x$) but since this is only a shift of the boundaries and the integrand, I omitted to explicitely write the substitution.

Comment: can you prove it $f(x+2)=f(x)$ i.e what algebraic operation i should apply to the given to the given conditions $f(2-x)=f(2+x) \ and f(4-x)=f(4+x)$ to reach at this $f(x+2)=f(x)$. I stuck to only this thing . I tried a lot but not succeed.

Comment: You cannot prove it, because it is in general not true. Every functon with a period of $2$ satisfies your condition, but a functionsatisfying the conditions has in general only a period of $4$.

Comment: in my question period is 2 or 4. By some replacements i got $f(x+4)=f(x) $ for all $x$.